# Refreshing desktop on windows

Tags: windows-7, desktop

I've searched the internet for this question, and I've found some answers, like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/404276/benefits-of-clicking-refresh-all-the-time-on-the-windows-desktop). All answers I can find say the same thing, that it refreshes the desktop folder, in other words, the icons.

My issue with this is that I'm running a windows 7 pc, that is incredibly slow, but when I press refresh, everything stops for half a sec, then runs smoothly again, if I instantly refresh again, it refreshes directly (not the half a second delay)

Before I searched the Internet for it I thought it could be the 'todo' list of the computer resetting, so when I refresh it just resets all its planned tasks and starts on a blank slate.

Now, if my 'refresh' click only updates the icons, why does everything seem to get resolved?

If there is no answer for this, other than

> it just refreshes the icons, the 'resloved' feeling is all in you
>   head

I'd like to know if there are any good software I can use to monitor what happens when in my computer, so I can see for myself what is going on.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, refresh button only affects the app/window that has the focus (the one you're looking at).

The best software for monitoring Windows is allready installed on it:

[Windows 7 and 2008 R2 Performance Monitoring Getting Started Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744567(v=ws.10).aspx)

Good luck!

Comment: I will try that monitoring and see where it gets me, thanks!